# Java Web Remote Development - Transform from Text Editor to IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

I am a 2 months olds developer in Java Web development (New Job). I want to check for a way to setup local development with IDE & able to debug/work with remote web server.

The current practise in my company is access the web server with sftp (WinSCP), edit file with any text editor, and upload back to linux web server, then either compile the java file & restart in webserver or refresh the content after uploaded the jsp file.
The company is currently using SVN for version control, the web server can be Oracle iPlanet Web server or Apache Tomcat server.

I had go through [Eclipse Remote Debugging](http://javarevisited.blogspot.sg/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html) but I cannot tell which project should I create at the beginning.
I tried to start with normal Java project, but unable to connect with the server.

Do forgive me if I asked this question in wrong section/wrong forum or maybe this seem pretty basic for you, and do point out which action I did wrongly and I supposed to find out more info/knowledge before proceed. Please do not use Intellij IDEA IDE (PAID IDE) as reference, due to currently is just my own idea to suggest a change from current development process in company, with no financial back up.

For database, I am totally satisfy with using Oracle SQL Developer to connect and develop.

Thanks for reading this.